# New : Write a Python function, square, that takes in one number and returns the square of that number

Tags: python

Write a Python function, twoPower, that takes in one number and returns that value raised to the fourth power.

condition : Use * just one time and "square" function twice.

Here is my code

```
def square(x):
    return x*x

def twoPower(x):   
   '''   x: int or float.
   '''   
   return square(square(x))

twoPower(3.12)
```

I want to know complete twoPower function code within use * just one time and 'square' function twice.

Comment: what's wrong with your code?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is correct just print output else assign to variable and print it:

```
>>> def square(x):
...     return x*x
... 
>>> def twoPower(x):   
...    '''   x: int or float.
...    '''   
...    return square(square(x))
... 
>>>print twoPower(3.12)
94.75854336000002
```

Calculate power values:

```
>>> 3.12*3.12
9.7344
>>> 9.7344*9.7344
94.75854336000002
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. BTW, I want code complete function twoPower(x) in condition Use * just one time and "square" function twice. That is my problem. Help me...

Comment: Ok .you can use math module >>> math.pow((3.12*3.12),2)

Answer (score 1):

Write a python3 function sqr( n ) that returns the square of its numeric parameter n.

```py
def sqr(n):
    x=n*n
    return x
```

or

```py
def sqr(n):
    return n * n
```

Answer (score 0):

As above, you need to output your number.

Alternatively:

> `num = twoPower(3.12)
>   print num`

Answer (score 0):

Satisfied your condition * at one time and square call 2 times.

```
def square(x):
    return x*x

def twoPower(x):
   '''   x: int or float.
   '''
   x1 =x;
   x=x*x;
   x=x/x1;

   return  square(square(x))

print twoPower(3.12)
```

~